# Load Balancing Utorrent

Tags: networking, load-balancing, bittorrent

I am a newbie into networking and stackoverlfow and it would be great if you could help me out with the following assuming if it was even possible:

I have two internet connections at home from two different ISP's over lan. I have 2 lan ports(Ubuntu PC) so i can connect to both simultaneously.Reading up on load balancing and software like nginx and HAproxy, **since utorrent uses TCP would it be possible to use my Ubuntu PC as load balancing server using(nginx,HAproxy or any other software) onto my two lan connections effectively increasing my bandwidth**.The client utorrent may be on the same PC(Load Balancer) or a different PC according to convenience.

If possible how so ? if not why?
Please give detailed answer so i can understand networking in general.
**Thank you so much!!**

**PC has Ubuntu 20.04**

Answer (score 0):

Since we buy ISP's service at home to get into network, the limitation of bandwidth comes from the ISP. How much you buy, how much the limitation is. So LB may not help you if you already reach the limitation.